# How to Show only first 5 elements of Array List in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview

> Hello, I am trying to Load only first 5 elements which I am fetching from an API . Currently, it is fetching all Items.

> This is my current code which displays all items :

> This is the Adapter code (i am not posting unnecessary methods)

```
  Context mCtx;
  List<VolleyModel> volleyModelList;

    public VolleyAdapter(Context mCtx, List<VolleyModel> volleyModelList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.volleyModelList = volleyModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return volleyModelList.size();
    }
```

> This is the Activity code :

```
  List<VolleyModel> volleyModelList;

 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, response -> {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    authorName = insideAuthorArray.getString("name");

                    volleyModelList.add(new VolleyModel(id, authorName));
                    volleyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("ERROR HomeFragment", e.getMessage());
                }
      volleyAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), volleyModelList);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(volleyAdapter);
```

> The above code **properly** displays every result which is returned by the server. What should I do so get `only the first 5 items` ?

Comment: @HenryTwist Like this :     for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)  . If this is so, then will it consider the respone variable which has all the data ?

Answer (score 2):

Just modify this method inside your adapter code:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size = volleyModelList.size();
    // Return at most 5 items from the ArrayList
    return (size > 5 ? 5 : size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try it like this , it will only show 5 items

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return volleyModelList.size();
          return 5;
    }
```